# Potentially superfluous iOS interface system

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface

I have written an interface system for iOS that allows interface elements to be moved around on the screen as actors move around on stage. It can operate within a `ViewController` environment. It relies on messaging through the Notification Centre (obviously not `LocalNotification`).

The central object is the `ARKView` object. It has '`ARKState` objects associated with it that contain information about where it should be (along with colour, alpha, transform, etc.) at each 'scene'.

My question:

I have Googled many moons to find a system which does this already. It turns out that having hundreds of objects on screen all sending each other notifications is not very efficient. Perhaps I can do it with delegates? I need a system in which I can precisely specify the position and properties of every element upon pressing a button or other stimulus.

[Code](https://bitbucket.org/nicholaspiano/sunriseappsystem)

**ARKView/receiveNotification:**

```
- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [notification userInfo];
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:State] && [self.stateDictionary count]!=0) {
        NSString *stateId = [dictionary objectForKey:StateId];
        NSString *sender = [dictionary objectForKey:Sender];

        [self syncStateWithId:stateId andSender:sender];
    }
}
```

For each `ARKView` object, this method above attempts to find a state object that matches the name of the notification sent from another object, if it is found, it 'syncs' the state, giving the `ARKView` object the attributes it needs for that scene.

Comment: Hi. The code works, but I'm running up against some performance issues with what I want to do. I was wondering if anyone more experienced than me would have any ideas about how to do the same thing a better way.

Comment: The link isn't particularly helpful given it required logging in to view the code.

Answer (score 6):

There is one performance issue that can be addressed quite easily, and that is when we're even bothering to respond to the notification.

This `if` statement can be completely eliminated:

```
if ([notification.name isEqualToString:State] && [self.stateDictionary count]!=0)
```

The left half of the `&&` can be eliminated by registering only for a specific notification.  The right half of the `&&` can be eliminated by registering/unregistering for the notification based on this property we're checking.

First, let's take care of registering/unregistering at appropriate times.

We only care about this notification if there's something in our `stateDictionary`, right?  So, let's unregister when it's empty, register when it's not.

```
- (void)setStateDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stateDictionary {
    _stateDictionary = stateDictionary;
    if ([stateDictionary count] > 0) {
        // register for notification
    } else {
        // unregister for notification
    }
}
```

Now our code is already better because our object is only getting a message from the notification center if our object is in a state where it would care about the notification.

Now, as for registering only for this specific notification.  That'd look something like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notifCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notifCenter addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                    name:State
                  object:nil];
```

We can make this better still if we have a reference to the specific object that might post the notification (if there's only one) and only listen to notifications of that type.

---

The important bit here is that now we're only listening to notifications that have the notification name we care about and we're only listening when our object is in a state that we would care about the notification.  The `if` statement itself isn't a particularly expensive bit of code, however `isEqualToString:` isn't a particularly cheap method either, and there's no reason to run this (effectively twice, because `NSNotificationCenter` is already going to look at the notification names when determining who to send it to).

We can now refactor our method which responds to the notification into simply this:

```
- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = notification.userInfo;
    NSString *stateId = dictionary[StateId];
    NSString *sender = dictionary[Sender];

    [self syncStateWithId:stateId andSender:sender];
}
```

And we'll get the same result.

So this code will run faster when it does receive the notification (because it skips the `if` check), and in general you'll be running faster overall because all the times that this method ran and the `if` check failed in the past, now the method will simply never be called and we'll never run through the `if` check.

Comment: That is very helpful. One problem that I am having is when I leave the app idle for two or three minutes, then perform some command such as a button press, there is some lag and the app jumps and starts. If I am pressing buttons quickly, this doesn't happen. Could this be because of how NSNotificationCenter works?

Comment: It might be because of how you're using `NSNotificationCenter`, but it won't be anything internal to `NSNotificationCenter`.  But it's really difficult to say, it could be any number of things.